# CSV to list of double arrays

Tags: java, arrays, list, csv, multidimensional-array

I am trying to put the contents of a csv file into a list of double arrays. I have a List of type double[] and was wondering how to populate the arrays inside it.

```
List <Double[]> lines = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
```

I previously added values to these arrays by doing:

```
while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null){ //while there is a line to read
String newLine = thisLine.replace("station_readings,", "");   //replace station headings with blank
lines.add(newLine.split(","));
```

But this only worked when the list was made up of string arrays.

Is there anyway to put the content from this csv file into an array of doubles.

Sample CSV contents:

```
name,time,frequency,targetPower,power,stateOfCharge
station_readings,2018-04-27T14:04:00.2Z,49932,273.093,294.469,49.2343
station_readings,2018-04-27T14:04:00.3Z,49922,313.299,292.487,49.2269
station_readings,2018-04-27T14:04:00.4Z,49932,273.093,292.235,49.2269
```

All suggestions appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

(NB - I should be getting a new csv where the date format is in ms rather than how it is presented here, thus making all values in the csv "numbers")

Comment: How can you convert `27T14:04:00.2Z` to a double?

Comment: @user7 "*I should be getting a new csv where the date format is in ms rather than how it is presented here, thus making all values in the csv "numbers"*"

Comment: I am going to be working with a different csv which is essentially the same but the date will be displayed in ms instead, so it will just be a number.

Comment: Just call `Double.valueOf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably want to use `double[]`, not `Double[]`.  “Double” and “double” are not the same—the capitalized version is a class, which means it incurs considerably more overhead than a simple number, which is just a few bytes.

Either way, you would use [Double.parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) to convert each CSV field, except the date field, which can be parsed with [Instant.parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
String[] fields = thisLine.split(",");

double[] values = new String[fields.length - 1];

Instant dateTime = Instant.parse(fields[1]);
values[0] = dateTime.toEpochMilli();

for (int i = 2; i < fields.length; i++) {
    values[i - 1] = Double.parseDouble[fields[i]);
}

lines.add(values);
```

Your comment indicates that the real CSV will not be the same as the sample CSV you’ve shared.  In that case, you can skip the use of Instant:

```
String[] fields = thisLine.split(",");

double[] values = new String[fields.length - 1];

for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
    values[i - 1] = Double.parseDouble[fields[i]);
}

lines.add(values);
```

However, as a matter of good design, you should not be using an array at all.  You should define a data class, so the meaning of each double value is clear:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Objects;

public class StationReading {
    private final String name;
    private final Instant time;
    private final double frequency;
    private final double targetPower;
    private final double power;
    private final double stateOfCharge;

    public StationReading(String name,
                          Instant time,
                          double frequency,
                          double targetPower,
                          double power,
                          double stateOfCharge) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.targetPower = targetPower;
        this.power = power;
        this.stateOfCharge = stateOfCharge;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Instant getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public double getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public double getTargetPower() {
        return targetPower;
    }

    public double getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public double getStateOfCharge() {
        return stateOfCharge;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() +
            "[name=\"" + name + "\"" +
            ", time=" + time +
            ", frequency=" + frequency +
            ", target power=" + targetPower +
            ", power=" + power +
            ", state of charge=" + stateOfCharge +
            "]";
    }

    public static StationReading fromLine(String line) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(line, "Line cannot be null.");

        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        if (fields.length != 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Cannot parse a line unless it has exactly six fields.");
        }

        String name = fields[0];

        Instant time = Instant.parse(fields[1]);
        // When you get a new CSV which represents times in milliseconds,
        // change the above to:
        //
        // double ms = Double.parseDouble(fields[1]);
        // Instant time = Instant.ofEpochMilli((long) ms);
        // time = time.plusNanos((long) ((ms - Math.floor(ms)) * 1_000_000));

        double frequency = Double.parseDouble(fields[2]);
        double targetPower = Double.parseDouble(fields[3]);
        double power = Double.parseDouble(fields[4]);
        double stateOfChange = Double.parseDouble(fields[5]);

        return new StationReading(name, time,
            frequency, targetPower, power, stateOfChange);
    }
}
```

Now, your read loop is simply:

```
List<StationReading> readings = new ArrayList<>();
while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StationReading reading = StationReading.fromLine(thisLine);
    readings.add(reading);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd stream the lines in the file, and then split each line and stream it individually:

```
List<double[]> lines = 
    Files.lines(Pathes.get("/path/to/file.csv"))
         .skip(1) // Skip the heading
         .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
                            .skip(1) // Skip the "station_readings"
                            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                            .toArray()
              )
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT:**

@user7 just pointed out that OP was looking for `List<Double[]>`. This is of course also possible in a similar way:

```
List<Double[]> lines = 
    Files.lines(Pathes.get("/path/to/file.csv"))
         .skip(1) // Skip the heading
         .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
                            .skip(1) // Skip the "station_readings"
                            .map(Double::new)
                            .toArray(Double[]::new)
              )
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `List<Double[]>`

Comment: @user7 good catch, thanks. I edited my answer to show how that can be one too

Comment: @T.Davies23 If this has helped you, you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If each line of your CSV has the format

```
station_readings,2018-04-27T14:04:00.3Z,49922,313.299,292.487,49.2269
```

The first two columns have data that can't be parsed to a `double`.

You can therefore only parse the remaining columns.

One way you can achieve this is by reading each line as you have done, into your `thisLine` variable.

Following this, you can split on the delimiter to get an array of strings:

```
String[] rowRaw = thisLine.split(",");
```

Then you can iterate that from the 3rd element to the end, parsing it to a double and putting it in an appropriately slzed `double[]`. This can then be added to your list.

```
double[] row = new double[rowRaw.length - 2];
for (int i=2; i<rowRaw.length; i++) {
    row[i - 2] = Double.parseDouble(rowRaw[i]);
}

lines.add(row);
```

If you want to parse the 2nd column (timestamp string) to a meaningful number, you can iterate as follows

```
double[] row = new double[rowRaw.length - 1];
row[0] = toDouble(rowRaw[1]);
for (int i=2; i<rowRaw.length; i++) {
    row[i - 2] = Double.parseDouble(rowRaw[i]);
}

lines.add(row);
```

With a method to convert the string to a double (a timestamp long stored as a double). You may have to tweak this, it's not tested.

```
double toDouble(String tsStr) {
    TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    sdf.setTimeZone(utc);
    Date date = sdf.parse(tsStr);
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(date.getTime());
}
```

Comment: @T.Davies23 You're welcome. Did the answer solve the problem?